# Prompt customization: how to detect when there is no tty

Tags: linux, bash, shell, prompt, bashrc

I have a customized prompt with colors (using tput) and every time I start a non-interactive session in the server I get a bunch of errors.
For instance if I start a non-interactive session like this:

```
ssh root@hostname6 "echo 'hello' ; echo $TERM"
```

The output I get is:

```
hello
xterm
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
stdin: is not a tty
```

So the $TERM variable has a value even when the session is non-interactive.

What condition do I have to detect so that when I start a non-interactive shell the prompt customization part is omited??

Comment: You need to show how you're customizing your prompt (and in which file). Because it's not supposed to do that.

Comment: I set the variable PS1 in the the file /etc/bashrc

Comment: Set it to what?

Comment: Also, are you sure it's /etc/bashrc and not /etc/bash.bashrc or ~/.bashrc?

Comment: It's basically "\u@\h \w" but with colors i.e. with several `tput setb 2` (and other colors) in between. And, yes, I'm sure it's /etc/bashrc. I just type "vi /etc/bashrc" to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tput` commands are evaluated at the time that the assignment to PS1 is made. Since the startup files are processed when an ssh session is started, the assignment is made even though your session is not interactive. You can test for that and only make your assignment when you are actually starting an interactive session.

```
if [[ $- =~ i ]]
then
    # set PS1 using tput
else
    # set a plain PS1 (or use hard-coded escape sequences)
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a bash built-in test for TTY. I forget when it was added, 3.0? I believe it's relatively new. I use it in scripts where I need different behavior when it's run from cron or a user runs it directly.

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then
   echo "I'm a TTY"
fi
```

Comment: This works only when you're logged in locally, but fails when you invoke the command remotely via ssh. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html

Answer (score 3):

Put the following at the beginning of /etc/bashrc

```
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

Comment: +1 this seems to be the technique many distributions use in the stock bashrc

Comment: How is this supposed to work? The PS1 variable doesn't exist when the shell is not interactive?

Comment: Yes. It is set by default for interactive shells and it is not for non-interactive ones.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a description of all 3 methods of doing this:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html